Vector bundles on pro-etale topology over a field
Suppose $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. Consider the one-point adic space $X=\operatorname{Spa}K$, and let $C=\hat {\bar K}$, $G=\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K)$. I heard that the category of $\hat{\mathcal O}_X$-vector bundles on $X_{proet}$ and $C$-representations of $G$ are equivalent. I wonder why?
It's clear that if I have a representation, then taking Galois invariants I get a vector bundle. But I don't know the inverse. If I have a vector bundle, then taking the section on $C$ we get a $C$-vector space, but how to define the $G$ action?
